# Append string as file upload using FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

I was wondering if I can upload string as file using form data. I believe there should be some `File` object, that can have `value`, `filename` and maybe also `mime-type` set.
Pseudo code:

```
var file = new File();
file.name = "file.txt";
file.mimeType = "text/plain";
file.value = "blah blah\nsecond line";
var data = new FormData();
data.append(file);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

works fine for me

```
const blob = new Blob(['blah blah\nsecond line'], {type : 'text/plain'})
formData.append('file', blob, 'file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. That type object as the second argument of Blob was what I've been looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here and using zag2art's answer but running into the error "Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream", you need to install the "form-data" package and use that to get past this error.

```
npm i --save form-data
```

Then you need to wrap the filename in an options object, and for me I had to switch to Buffer instead of Blob as although theoretically supported causes a new error.

```
import FormData = require('form-data');

...

const blob = Buffer.from('here is the text you want to upload', 'utf8');
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, {filename: 'file.txt'});
```

Answer (score -8):

There is indeed an object called `File`(on modern browsers), but you cannot create a new instance of it, out of security issues. Therefore, what you seek is not possible.

Comment: What OP is trying to do is possible. See [zag2art's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951548/1104581) below.

Comment: i don't know whether you tried to reproduce the scenario or test the code but this Ans should not be marked as answer, as the solution from @zag2art's is clearly working, which shows modern browsers does allow what was asked in the question.

Comment: @ipetrik This answer was posted in 2013, back then it was correct afaik. I changed accepted answer now that we have file related APIs